# Проблема с выводом переменной типа float

Tags: c, float, printf

Возник непонятный момент, при выводе переменных типа float.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float a = 123456789;
    printf("%f",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Следующий код как я думал, должен вывести **123456789**, однако, в реальной ситуации он выводит **123456792.000000**. Если попробовать ввести что то более простое, например 900000008 то исчезает последняя цифра 8. Если тоже самое произвести с типом int, все прекрасно выводится. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в свои 4 байта этот тип должен воткнуть не только значение, но и показатель степени. Грубо говоря, представление внутри `float` - значение, приведенное к диапазону [0,1) и показатель степени. Вот и не хватает для точного представления.

(Disclaimer: для знатоков - да, я знаю, это очень приближенное пояснение, про нормальную и нормализованную формы и прочее... не думаю, что все это надо рассказывать для ответа на заданный вопрос)

И вообще - не пытайтесь подменять приближенным по определению числом с плавающей точкой точное целочисленное...

Посмотрите, например, тут - https://habrahabr.ru/post/112953/